# Angle between vector and $x$-axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

I have to find to component of vector DE having magnitude 1 m .now the vector is in 4th quad  making angle 90 degree with postive x axis 
The solution that my teacher showed is  ax=1cos(270) .and ay = 1sin(270) ...
Now my confusion is that if it makes 90 degree with x axis ....why not ax=1cos90 and ay=1sin90
.........my refrence shows ax=0 and ay=-1

Comment: $\cos 90^o = \cos 270^o =0$.

Comment: But sin90 is not equal to sin270

Comment: Note that the angles are measured counter-clockwise with respect to the positive $x$ axis.

Comment: Draw a picture - think why the angle might in fact be $-90^\circ$ or equivalently $270^\circ$. Something to do with those quadrants

Comment: @innisfree: 4. quadrant $90^o$ means a unit vector pointing downwards in the $-y$ direction :)

Comment: So your saying that by measuring an angle counterclockwise ,it should be like 90 +180=270 degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture...

[image]

From here the answer should be obvious. Don't focus just on the math - look at what is actually going on.

Comment: Thanx ,but i still dont understand how it works ,say we have to resolve a vector with magnitude 1 which lies in fourth quad (3,-4)...which is parallal to y axis ....what will be its angle with x axis

Comment: By convention we measure angles as I drew in my diagram: start at X axis and work counter clockwise. That makes the angle of the vector I drew 270°, and you get (0,-1) in vector notation $(\cos 270°, \sin 270°$) . The result is the same if you use an angle of -90°

Comment: Oh thanxs a lot ...i got you ..thanx a ton